# Performance Testing through distributed jmeter instances and bamboo

Tags: performance, testing, maven, jmeter, bamboo

I´m working on performance test for several services running in an Amazon network.

Our architecture is:

- Continuous Integration server running in our facilities (Bamboo);
- A Jmeter server instance in the same network than the services to test;
- A Jmeter client connected to the JMeter server (ssh tunnels) in our facilities.

I want to start the execution of tests from bamboo, and see the different results on it too.

```
Bamboo with    <--------->   Jmeter server <-------->  WebService
Jmeter client                  on Amazon                on Amazon
```

Has anybody tried something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, it is better and easier to keep the JMeter client and server in the same subnet and not use tunnels. Better because you don't introduce the problem of latency when transferring results data and easier because tunnelling RMI is just not fun.

I would imagine that the simplest solution would be to tell Bamboo to execute a shell script and then use this script to control starting the test and managing the results. If you have an ec2 host with JMeter installed then you can just execute the test using ssh. Something like (simplified for brevity):

```
ssh -i /mykey.pem root@myec2host.com ./path/to/jmeter -n -t /path/to/mytest.jmx -l /my/results.jtl
```

I took a similar approach for a requirement I had a while back and it grew into [this](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2). Probably excessive for your needs but feel free to pull it apart if there's anything of use in it.

In terms of seeing the results in bamboo, this is going to be a custom process. JMeter will give you a csv or xml file for each individual test which you can read and visualise using it's GUI but for CI you'll benefit from a solution that trends results over multiple test runs (Ie. multiple builds of the code). For this you'll want to put the results in some form of store, probably a database, and then query them to get the most useful representations.

If you're only interested in simple averages then this can actually be quite easy. Just use the shell script to awk the data when the test is complete to grab some summary values and pipe these into a table. Or, and this might be even easier, see what the Bamboo API offers. You might find you can import results for each build directly and then use the Bamboo tool to view results. It all depends on what level of reporting you need.